# How can I compare two Json arrays at Python?

Tags: python, arrays, json, monitoring, netapp

I am creating a script that allows comparing two ssh command outputs to a remote Netapp, and that allows comparing between a current value and the maximum value of space that the Netapp cabin has.

I have collected these values ​​in two dictionaries (rv and rv 2), which in turn, I convert to JSON format to be able to compare them based on the warning argument passed to it (if it exceeds this limit, it would have to notify).

```
import subprocess
import argparse
import sys
import json
import re
from subprocess import check_output
def parse_args(argv):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()  
    parser.add_argument("-u", "--user", action="store",
                        help="User for login",
                        dest="user")
    parser.add_argument("-p", "--pwd", action="store",
                        help="Password",
                        dest="pwd")
    parser.add_argument("-i", "--ip", action="store",
                        help="Machine ip",
                        dest="ip")
    parser.add_argument("-w", "--warning", action="store",
                        help="Warning threshold",
                        type = int,
                        dest="warning")
    parser.add_argument("-m", "--machine_command", action="store",
                        help="Command",
                        type = int,
                        dest="ssh_command")
    parser.add_argument("-M", "--machine_command_max", action="store",
                        help="Max value for command",
                        type = int,
                        dest="ssh_command_max")



    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args
args = parse_args(sys.argv[1:])

command = 'sshpass -p ' +args.pwd+ ' ssh ' + args.user + '@' +args.ip+ args.ssh_command 
output = check_output(command, shell=True)
#Command to retrieve the max_values
command_max = 'sshpass -p ' +args.pwd+ ' ssh ' + args.user + '@' +args.ip+ args.ssh_command_max
output_max = check_output(command_max, shell=True)


rv = {}
current_node = None

for match in re.findall(r'Machine_name (name.*\d+)|(Metric_name_.*)', output):
    node, metric = match
    if node and current_node != node:
       current_node = node
    if current_node and metric:
        name, value = metric.strip().split()
        rv[current_node.strip() + "." + name.replace("Alloc", "")] = [value] 
#print(';'.join(rv))

rv2 = {}
current_node = None

for match in re.findall(r'Machine_name (name.*\d+)|(Max_metric.*)', output_max):
    node, metric = match
    if node and current_node != node:
        current_node = node
    if current_node and metric:
        name, value = metric.strip().split()
        rv2[current_node.strip() + "." + name.replace("Max", "")] = [(value/100) * args.warning] 

json1=json.dumps(rv, sort_keys=True)
json2=json.dumps(rv2, sort_keys=True)



def get_values(json, lst):
  if isinstance(json, list):
    for item in json: get_values(item, lst)
  elif isinstance(json, dict):
    for item in json.values(): get_values(item, lst)
  else: lst.append(json)


list1 = []; get_values(json1, list1)
list2 = []; get_values(json2, list2)

diff = [(n, x, y) for n,(x,y) in enumerate(zip(list1, list2)) if x <= y]
print(diff)
```

**An example of the values that I would like to compare:**
RV1:

```
{'node1.storePool_Owner': ['160'], 'node1.storePool_Deleg': ['0'], 'node2.storePool_LockState': ['0']}
```

RV2:

```
{'node1.storePool_Owner': ['1024000'], 'node1.storePool_Deleg': ['1024000'], 'node2.storePool_LockState': ['1024000']}
```

The idea is to compare each of these values, with their maximum equivalent.

Thanks a lot for your help.

**An example of how should the comparison be:**
If this node, with that value:

```
node1.storePool_Owner': ['160']
```

Reaches the X% (warning arg) of:

```
node1.storePool_Owner': ['1024000']
```

Then it should return:

```
WARNING: node1.storePool_Owner has exceeded the threshold (x%)
```

Comment: What do you want the result of your comparison to be? Or are you asking for advice about what the result of the comparison should be? Also consider a [example]. If you only want advice on how to compare two JSON arrays - your code should be 4 lines tops. Also, does it matter that the arrays have a JSON representation? Are you just comparing Python arrays?

Comment: Hello @JohnFilleau , I already edited my questoion with an example of how would I like to compare all values with his equal. I chose to compare Json because I though that it could be easier (I am new at Python, and some basic things I do not master, or do not know how to look for them). I have put the entire code, so you can see the dictionary conversion to json, and if you even consider it better not to make that change (although from what I was looking at, it was the simplest for me).

Comment: The object in a dictionary is the most convenient for comparisons. If you have it in a JSON text format, then to compare, you'd have to... parse it back to some logical representation such as a python dictionary to compare it anyway. You just wrote your own code by the way: `If this node with that value... reaches this other value... then it should return <some message that's a combination of programmer-specified message stated numeric limits>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will compare the two json files/dictionaries. I noticed the values are lists of string... is that intentional?

```py
import json


def open_json(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as file:
        return json.load(file)


def check_thresholds(data, thresholds):
    for k, v in thresholds.items():
        # your logic/output here
        # k[0] and v[0] because your values are lists of strings... should they be just int of float?
        difference = int(data.get(k)[0]) - int(v[0])
        if difference >= 0:
            print(f'WARNING: {k} has exceeded the threshold by {difference}')
        else:
            print(f'OK: {k}')


def main():
    # load the data into dictionaries
    data = open_json('./rv.json')
    thresholds = open_json('./rv2.json')

    # if your data is a dictionary and not json files then use these
    # data = {'node1.storePool_Owner': ['160'], 'node1.storePool_Deleg': ['0'], 'node2.storePool_LockState': ['0']}
    # thresholds = {'node1.storePool_Owner': ['1024000'], 'node1.storePool_Deleg': ['1024000'], 'node2.storePool_LockState': ['1024000']}

    # run the checks
    check_thresholds(data, thresholds)


main()
```

Output (I modified some values to show the warning):

```
WARNING: node1.storePool_Owner has exceeded the threshold by 1000
OK: node1.storePool_Deleg
OK: node2.storePool_LockState
```

Comment: Hello! Yes, the values are strings because they are extracted from a SSH command.